# Get Max from column datatable or Default Value using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have a linq query that looks into a datatable column and gets the max value in that field, I am running into an error in which when the datatable has no rows the query is throwing an exception. I was wondering if I can handle this secnario by putting a DefaultIfEmpty but just dont know how to use it. This is the working linq query:

```
Datatable.AsEnumerable().Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Field<string>(Framework.SomeStringField)))
```

this gets the max value of that column, how do I handle return 0 if there are no rows in the datatable by using DefaultifEmpty if that is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
Datatable.AsEnumerable()
         .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Field<string>(Framework.SomeStringField)))
         .DefaultIfEmpty(0)
         .Max(x => x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way

```
int max = dataTable.AsEnumerable().Any() ? dataTable.AsEnumerable().Max(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Field<string>(Framework.SomeStringField))): 0
```

Comment: dataTable.AsEnumerable().Any() errors out bec I have dt.Rows.Count is 0

Comment: No. Any() checks for any items in the collection. did you compare the dataTable null